# How to check if Spark is using OpenBlas?

Tags: java, apache-spark, ubuntu, blas, openblas

I recently downloaded and built Spark 2.3.1. I used these commands to download and select version 2.3.1

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/spark.git   
cd spark
git checkout tags/v2.3.1
```

I am looking to improve the performance of my application and came across articles that suggested updating the distributed version of OpenBLAS so while building spark I used the `-Pnetlib-lgpl` option to install `netlib-java`.

This is the command I used.

```
build/mvn -Pyarn -Phive -Phive-thriftserver  -DskipTests -Pnetlib-lgpl clean package
```

How do I know/ensure that spark now uses the OpenBLAS from netlib-java I installed with the command above rather than the one distributed with Ubuntu?
Also, is this the right way to go about updating OpenBLAS or am I missing out on something?

**PS**

I ran the following commands to see if it is correctly installed

```
import com.github.fommil.netlib.BLAS
println(BLAS.getInstance().getClass().getName())
```

results in

```
com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
```

I used the following for the links

```
sudo update-alternatives --display liblapack.so
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib64/libblas.so libblas.so /usr/lib64/atlas/libtatlas.so.3 1000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3 libblas.so.3 /usr/lib64/atlas/libtatlas.so.3 1000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib64/liblapack.so liblapack.so /usr/lib64/atlas/libtatlas.so.3 1000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3 liblapack.so.3 /usr/lib64/atlas/libtatlas.so.3 1000
```

I am using Ubuntu

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've confirmed that Spark uses a native BLAS library, use `lsof` to find out which one exactly is loaded by the JVM process hosting the worker. Loaded libraries show up as memory mapped regular files in the output of `lsof`. Here is an example of Spark using Intel MKL:

```
$ lsof -n -p 10202
...
java  10202 ubuntu  mem  REG  8,1  70211598  519025 /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.3.199/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_core.so
java  10202 ubuntu  mem  REG  8,1    902768  521066 /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.3.199/linux/mkl/wrapper/mkl_wrapper.so
...
```

10202 is the PID of the JVM process. The output contains the full path to each opened file, so you can easily tell if the correct library is being used.